# How do I update multiple columns in a table with one checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-5.2

We're developing an in-house C.M.S. to keep track of our customers, relevant information, and to track issues that those customers have.  To that end, we have a couple of columns in our "tickets" table - we have a "completed" boolean, a "completed_at" datetime, and a "completed_by" integer.

We're trying to come up with a couple of U.I. methods by which we could close a ticket - and in the "Edit Ticket" page, we want to have a single checkbox that we could check that would updated all three of those columns:

1. "completed" from false to true
2. "completed_at" from null to Time.now
3. "completed_by" from null to current_user.id

We've tried a couple of different approaches from all over the web, but we're not entirely sure how we'd do this.

---

**EDIT:** 26 June 2018

Here's our "update" action in our tickets_controller.rb:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @ticket }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

---

**EDIT:** 27 June 2018

Here's the solution I ultimately arrived at.  In `routes.rb`, I changed:

```
resources :tickets
```

to:

```
resources :tickets do
  member do
    patch :close_ticket
  end
end
```

Then, in our Tickets controller, I added the following function:

```
def close_ticket
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  @ticket.update(:completed => true, :completed_at => Time.now, :completed_by => current_user.id)
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Ticket ##{@ticket.id} was successfully closed."
end
```

With that, I was able to add the following button to any view:

```
<%= link_to "Close", close_ticket_ticket_path(ticket), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-sm btn-warning table-btn" %>
```

Seems to work pretty well and even hide certain stuff from the view such that a savvy user couldn't input bad date data if they wanted to, which is nice - but upon reading up on [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and the `tap` method, I'm convinced that [@mmichael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461294/mmichael)'s solution is probably a better approach, so I'm marking it as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could easily be done with a [check_box_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag).

For example, in your edit form view (assuming you're using strong params):

```
<%= check_box_tag 'ticket[completed]', @ticket.id %>
```

Then, you could just update `ticket_params` in your controller:

```
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(..., :completed).tap do |params|
    if params[:completed]
      params[:completed] = true
      params[:completed_at] = Time.now
      params[:completed_by] = current_user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that this approach assumes that "completing" a ticket is non-reversible via the update action. You could add logic to allow to reverse the "completion" (and therefore reverting those attributes), but you'd need to update your `ticket_params` method again.

If you don't want to `tap` strong params, you could always explicitly set the attributes based on the value of that `completed` checkbox. This will also allow you to reverse "completion" by checking for a `false` value for your `completed` checkbox.

And these are just a couple of ways this can be done. You certainly have options.

Comment: Interesting!  I'm just beginning to get familiar with Ruby on Rails (working with version 5.2), so I'm not sure I'm familiar with the `tap` method is, but this seems like pretty interesting code!  I arrived at a different solution (which I will update my post to include), but I had thought about an approach like yours, but had no idea you could SET parameters in the `<model>_params` statement!  This is super helpful, I appreciate it!

Comment: Your solution is perfectly acceptable. One thing I would add is some logic to check if the ticket is already closed before doing the update. Also, keep in mind that `update` will fail silently (return false) so with your current code, you don't really have error handling. You could use `update!`, which will raise an exception if the update fails, or check if `update` succeeds/fails and render/redirect as needed.